# Matlab solution for two graphs

Tags: matlab, plot, solution, equation-solving

I have a function f(t) and want to get all the points where it intersects y=-1 and y=1 in the range 0 to 6*pi.
The only way I cold do it is ploting them and trying to locate the x-axis pt where f(t) meets the y=1 graph. But this doesn't give me the exact point. Instead gives me a near by value. [image: This is how I am getting the points.]

```
clear;
clc;
f=@(t) (9*(sin(t))/t) + cos(t);
fplot(f,[0 6*pi]);
hold on; plot(0:0.01:6*pi,1,'r-');
         plot(0:0.01:6*pi,-1,'r-');
         x=0:0.2:6*pi; h=cos(x); plot(x,h,':')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to solve a system of two equations, at least in general. For the simple case where one of the equations is a constant, thus y = 1, we can solve it using fzero. Of course, it is always a good idea to use graphical means to find a good starting point.

```
f=@(t) (9*(sin(t))./t) + cos(t);
y0 = 1;
```

The idea is if you want to find where the two curves intersect, is to subtract them, then look for a root of the resulting difference.

(By the way, note that I used ./ for the divide, so that MATLAB won't have problem for vector or array input in f. This is a good habit to develop.)

Note that f(t) is not strictly defined in MATLAB at zero, since it results in 0/0. (A limit exists of course for the function, and can be evaluated using my [limest](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20058-adaptive-numerical-limit-estimation) tool.)

```
limest(f,0)
ans =
           10
```

Since I know the solution is not at 0, I'll just use the fzero bounds from looking there for a root.

```
format long g
fzero(@(t) f(t) - y0,[eps,6*pi])
ans =
          2.58268206208857
```

But is this the only root? What if we have two or more solutions? Finding all the roots of a completely general function can be a nasty problem, as some roots may be infinitely close together, or there may be infinitely many roots.

One idea is to use a tool that knows how to look for multiple solutions to a problem. Again, found on the file exchange, we can use [research](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13733-rmsearch).

```
y0 = 1;
rmsearch(@(t) f(t) - y0,'fzero',1,eps,6*pi)
ans =
          2.58268206208857
          6.28318530717959
          7.97464518075547
          12.5663706143592
          13.7270312712311

y0 = -1;
rmsearch(@(t) f(t) - y0,'fzero',1,eps,6*pi)
ans =
          3.14159265358979
          5.23030501095915
          9.42477796076938
          10.8130654321854
           15.707963267949
          16.6967239156574
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time in explaining me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y = fplot(f,[0 6*pi]);
```

now you can analyse `y` for the value you are looking for.

```
[x,y] = fplot(f,[0 6*pi]);
[~,i] = min(abs(y-1));
point = x(i);
```

this will find one, nearest crossing point. Otherwhise you going through the vector with `for`

Comment: thanks. but What I want is the corresponding points when my f(t) intersects the y=1 line.

Comment: the point I get is 1.0179 which is clearly not where my function intersects the y=1 line.

Comment: Find the the point before and after the y=1 line, and then interpolate using `interp1` to find the corresponding value for `y=1`.

Comment: I have fix it - it was too late at night :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the variant with `for` I often use:

```
clear;
clc;
f=@(t) (9*(sin(t))/t) + cos(t);
fplot(f,[0 6*pi]);
[fx,fy] = fplot(f,[0 6*pi]);
hold on; plot(0:0.01:6*pi,1,'r-');
         plot(0:0.01:6*pi,-1,'r-');
         x=0:0.2:6*pi; h=cos(x); plot(x,h,':')

k  = 1; % rising 
kt = 1; % rising
pn = 0; % number of crossings
fy = abs(fy-1);
for n = 2:length(fx)
    if fy(n-1)>fy(n)
        k = 0; % falling
    else
        k = 1; % rising
    end

    if k==1 && kt ==0 % change from falling to rising
        pn = pn +1;
        p(pn) = fx(n);
    end
    kt = k;
end
```

You can make this faster, if you make an mex-file of this...